# What bluetooth service is needed to connect a remote BLE device to a windows 10 virtual port?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, hci, bluenrg

I am doing some bluetooth development where I have a device running a SPP service. However i cannot set up a virtual comport where with the device. Windows discovers the device in the general bluetooth tab but when looking in the browse window in: More bluetooth options -> COM ports -> Add... -> Outgoing -> Browse, I cannot find the device.

Remote device info:

```
    Name: BP
    Alias: BP
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: no
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: RFCOMM                    (00000003-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Serial Port               (00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    RSSI: -43
    TxPower: 8
```

What services are required to be able to establish a virtual comport connection with my device? Are there any special requirments on characteristics?

SPP should be supported according to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10568/windows-10-supported-bluetooth-profiles

Comment: Does this require a code writing solution?

Comment: No, I just want to be able to rout the incomming data to a terminal